# MS Access VBA - Private Subs with Same Name

Tags: vba, ms-access, subroutine

I have a database which has an 'exit database' button on every form.

I have an event procedure that is executed 'on-click', every 'exit database' button in the database has the same sub name  : `Private Sub exitDatabase_Click()`

Each sub contains slightly different exit conditions. I have not yet come across an error but could having the same name for all my 'exit database' buttons cause an error somewhere down the line even though they are all private subs and exist on different forms? I wouldn't have thought so as they're private but I'm not sure.

Comment: No, that is not an issue.

Comment: As an addition: Every form (and its code) is like a class itself, so encapsulated. Even if you declare such procedures `Public` it won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Each private sub is private to that form, meaning that it wont interfere with the other forms private subs. If you have multiple public subs with the same name, then that will pose a problem (overloading is not directly supported in vba)